# I want to use a javascript variable to store an image location

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm pretty new to coding in javascript, and am currently making pop up notifications for a website in order to give feedback to users. I have searched around a bit and know there is a way to do this, but can't get my head wrapped around it. I need to store an image location to a variable in my javascript that I can reference in my html page, enabling me to output a different icon image on my toast notification based on the type that is called (error, more info, warning, ect). This is my code so far:

```
<div id="toast">
    <div id ="title" style="<some styling code>"></div>
    <img id ="icon" style="<image style code>"/>
</div>
```

And my script:

```
function showTypeOfToast()
{
    var i = document.getElementById("toast")
    i.className = "showTypeOfToast";
    var label = "Type Of Toast";
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = label
    var img = "imgsrc.png";
    var iconElement = document.getElementById("icon");
    iconElement.src = img;
}
```

My title element works as I expect it to, and I am wanting the image element to work in the same way.

Cheers

Comment: That should work if the `"imgsrc.png"` file is at the same level in your folder structure as your HTML file. Impossible for us to know whether that's the case though.

Comment: Your code should be working. Are you sure that 'imgsrc.png' is a valid image, located in the same folder as the script?

Comment: I have a folder of icons in the same directory as my script, and I've included the path to the images in my script, just didn't include those pathways on the code I wrote on here

Comment: write the entire path from http:// to the filetype, sometimes that can help. if the image still isnt appearing, i cant tell you why lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass a parameter into showTypeOfToast. Pass in the type of toast you want to show.
then inside the function define something like:

```
if (type == warning)
iconElement.src = "warning.jpg";
else if (type == help)
iconElement.src = "help.jpg";
```

`document.getElementById('imageId').src = 'x.jpg';` should work in any case.

or you can state:

```
var x = "www.yoursite.com/your-image.jpg";
var y = "www.yoursite.com/your-image2.jpg";
```

then `document.getElementById('imageId').src = x;`
and `document.getElementById('imageId').src = y;`
work

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly, wasn't expecting that. My image is now not available when it loads, but that'll be a whole separate problem for me to figure out. Your change at least got it to appear in my notification, and I like passing a parameter instead of calling a separate function for each type as I previously was doing